# how to use Lookup activity and if activity together

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

i have a file on storage account emp.csv that contains. i want that from storage account a file and b file would go to database table.

```
emp_id,filename
   1,a
   2,b
   3,anubhav
```

so for this i pass emp.csv file on lookup activity as source dataset then i use foreach activity
[image]

Inside foreach activity i used a if condition on expression

```
@equals(item().filename,'anubhav' )
```

[image]

if this expression is true then wait activity will come and wait for 1 sec. if this expression false then
[image]

but this pipeline is failing

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline is failing because inside copy activity dataset properties it should be a string, but you have given it as an array value `@activity('Lookup1').output.value`. because of that, you getting an error.

Try to replace the array value with the string `@item().filename` as you can see, I reproduce the same thing in my environment and got this output.

[image]

You can use this **Json pipeline activity**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Lookup1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Lookup1').output.value",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "If Condition1",
                            "type": "IfCondition",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "expression": {
                                    "value": "@equals(item().filename, 'anubhav.csv')",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "ifFalseActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Copy data1",
                                        "type": "Copy",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "policy": {
                                            "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                            "retry": 0,
                                            "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                            "secureOutput": false,
                                            "secureInput": false
                                        },
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "source": {
                                                "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                                                "storeSettings": {
                                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                                    "recursive": true,
                                                    "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                                                },
                                                "formatSettings": {
                                                    "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "sink": {
                                                "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                                                "storeSettings": {
                                                    "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                                },
                                                "formatSettings": {
                                                    "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                                                    "quoteAllText": true,
                                                    "fileExtension": ".txt"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "enableStaging": false,
                                            "translator": {
                                                "type": "TabularTranslator",
                                                "typeConversion": true,
                                                "typeConversionSettings": {
                                                    "allowDataTruncation": true,
                                                    "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "inputs": [
                                            {
                                                "referenceName": "abcsv",
                                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                                "parameters": {
                                                    "file": {
                                                        "value": "@item().filename",
                                                        "type": "Expression"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "outputs": [
                                            {
                                                "referenceName": "DelimitedText2",
                                                "type": "DatasetReference",
                                                "parameters": {
                                                    "file": {
                                                        "value": "@item().filename",
                                                        "type": "Expression"
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "ifTrueActivities": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "Wait1",
                                        "type": "Wait",
                                        "dependsOn": [],
                                        "userProperties": [],
                                        "typeProperties": {
                                            "waitTimeInSeconds": 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

> **Pipeline successfully executed**

[image]

Comment: While debugging it i have to pass emp.csv file right? where you pass @item().filename

Comment: hi @Anubhav, check above json you get an idea how to pass emp.csv file

Comment: otherwise, you can use same Json pipeline activity.